# Local declaration of 'imgView' hides instance variable (app crashes)

Tags: ios, objective-c, warnings

If I debug my app. The app crashes in this line of code and I get this warning:

**Warning:**

```
Local declaration of 'imgView' hides instance variable
```

**Line of code:**

```
[brightnessFilter forceProcessingAtSize:imgView.sizeInPixels];
```

**Block of code:**

```
- (IBAction)sliderBrightness:(id)sender {

    UIImage *inputImage = imgView.image;

    sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
    brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];

    GPUImageView *imgView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
    [brightnessFilter forceProcessingAtSize:imgView.sizeInPixels]; 

    [sourcePicture addTarget:brightnessFilter];
    [brightnessFilter addTarget:imgView];

    [sourcePicture processImage];
}
```

Can someone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: imgView Declare two time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrey gave you the basics. To be very specific.

Here is your current code:

```
- (IBAction)sliderBrightness:(id)sender {

    UIImage *inputImage = imgView.image; // <--- This line refers to an instance var

    sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
    brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];

    GPUImageView *imgView = (GPUImageView *)self.view; <--- This line defines a local
    [brightnessFilter forceProcessingAtSize:imgView.sizeInPixels]; 

    [sourcePicture addTarget:brightnessFilter];
    [brightnessFilter addTarget:imgView];

    [sourcePicture processImage];
}
```

Look at the to comments I added that start with " <--- This line". The first one marks your reference to an instance variable imgView.

The second comment marks a place where you define a different, local variable with the same name, imgView.

If you intend to use a different local variable, change that name to something else, like

```
    GPUImageView *theGPUimgView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
```

If you intend to change the instance variable, then make it an assignment, and get rid of the variable declaration:

```
   imgView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
```

I'm guessing that you want the second case, where you change the contents of the instance variable, but I'm not sure. It's your code.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Now I didn't get the warning anymore, but if I debug this line of code: `[brightnessFilter forceProcessingAtSize:imgView2.sizeInPixels];` the app is still crashing.

Comment: Ok, so look at imagView2 when you hit the breakpoint. Is it nil? Is the value of imageView2.sizeInPixels reasonable? Can you step into the `forceProcessingAtSize:` method and see where it's crashing? You need to debug the crash.

Comment: No, imgView2 is not nil and I also can't debug the crash/step into the method. But it's a SIGABRT crash.

Comment: But this is the log: `2014-05-13 16:04:46.671 Picxxr[5341:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView sizeInPixels]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109fbed60'`

Comment: Ok that tells me what's going on. You have a variable imgView that is supposed to point to an object of type GPUImageView. Thew crash you are getting tells you that instead, the view is a generic UIView. You need to change the view to be of type GPUImageView. Usually, this means going into your storyboard, selecting the view, going to the identity inspector, and changing the type to the desired class (in this case, GPUImageView). That should fix the problem.

Comment: Always, always, always provide as much detailed information as you can about a crash. What is the exact message in the log. What link of code?

Comment: That's all information material which I get. I changed the class to GPUImageView, but it's still crashing.

Comment: Sigh. Again you have failed to provide critical information. What's the new message in the console when you crash? And on what line of code?

Comment: Ok. Now I change the class from UIView to GPUImageView. But if I'll run my app it crashes. Xcode says: 2014-05-27 21:25:36.181 CameraApp[6112:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView sizeInPixels]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109d19930' and here -[UIView  it says that it is an UIView. But why? I changed it to GPUImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code:

```
GPUImageView *imgView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
[brightnessFilter forceProcessingAtSize:imgView.sizeInPixels]; 

[sourcePicture addTarget:brightnessFilter];
[brightnessFilter addTarget:imgView];
```

with this code:

```
GPUImageView *imgView2 = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
[brightnessFilter forceProcessingAtSize:imgView2.sizeInPixels]; 

[sourcePicture addTarget:brightnessFilter];
[brightnessFilter addTarget:imgView2];
```

You have 2 variables with the name `imgView` which is giving you the warning, but there is no reason for this to cause the crash. The crash is because of some other reason which is outside of the code you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared two variables(Local and Instance) with name imgView.Change the local variable instance of GPUImageView from imgView to some other name say gpuimgView

```
- (IBAction)sliderBrightness:(id)sender {

    UIImage *inputImage = imgView.image;

    sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
    brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];

    GPUImageView *gpuimgView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;//changed to gpuimgView
    [brightnessFilter forceProcessingAtSize:gpuimgView.sizeInPixels]; 

    [sourcePicture addTarget:brightnessFilter];
    [brightnessFilter addTarget:gpuimgView];

    [sourcePicture processImage];
}
```

Hope it will helps you....